# Discord bot not updating the time and only keeps printing the time when it started running (Node/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var moment = require('moment');


const token = '//not telling you this';

const PREFIX = '!';



client.on('ready', () =>{
console.log('SaltBot is online');
})



var a = moment().format('LTS');


client.on('message', message=>{

let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

 switch(args[0]){
    case 'ping':
       message.channel.send('pong!')
       break;
}


switch(args[0]){
    case 'Server':
            message.channel.send('Server status at ' + a , {files: ["//not telling either"]});
```

So i made this code for my discord bot, which basically sends an image of the minecraft servers status banner, when someone types !Server status. I also wanted to include time in the same message, so I used moment for it. The problem is, once the bot is running, everytime you ask for the Server status update, it tells you the same time as when it comes online.

I'm very new at coding, but decided that it would be time to start learning it, sorry if this is an obvious case. I just need the bot to tell the current time, every time someone types !Server status in the chat.

Comment: Yes, this is my first code outside of very barebone html website coding 3 years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `moment().format('LTS')` gets the current time *at the time it's evaluated*.

It matters when you tell the interpreter to evaluate that, because that's the time you'll get. Right now you're assigning that to `a` outside of your message handler, which means it's part of your bot's initial startup - during startup you get the current time, save it, and now you're using that unchanging time for the command. It will only ever be evaluated and saved once in your bot's lifetime.

You should move the expression `moment().format('LTS')` into your command so it gets evaluated fresh every time you run the command, like this:

```
message.channel.send('Server status at ' + moment().format('LTS') , {files: ["//not telling either"]});
```